# Select / group by multiple columns but count just the values of one column

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have 2 tables.

Table #1: orders

```
order_id    | crit_1 | crit_2 | crit_3     | other
01      | A00    | GER    | 49er       | x    
02      | A00    | GER    | 49er       | x    
03      | A00    | USA    | 49er       | x    
04      | C80    | DEN    | 66er       | x    
05      | B50    | GER    | 99er       | x
```

The table `orders` has 3 important criteria but doesn't have the `criterion_4`. There is another table with the `order_positions` which contains multiple `criterion_4` entries for each `order_id`.

Table #2: classifications

```
crit_1 | crit_2 | crit_3 | crit_4 | class_1 | class_2
A00    | GER    | 49er   | 4711   | A       | 11
A00    | GER    | 49er   | 4712   | A       | 21
A00    | USA    | 49er   | 4711   | D       | 12
A00    | USA    | 49er   | 4712   | D       | 21
B50    | GER    | 99er   | 4801   | B       | 12
B50    | GER    | 99er   | 4802   | B       | 12
B50    | GER    | 99er   | 4803   | B       | 14
C80    | DEN    | 66er   | 4904   | C       | 22
C80    | DEN    | 66er   | 4905   | C       | 21
```

The table `classifications` contains classifications for:

- `orders = class_1 = combination of crit_1, crit_2 & crit_3`
- `order_positions = class_2 = combination of crit_1, crit_2, crit_3
  & crit_4`

I have a query where I join `classifications.class_1` on the table `orders` to create a list of all `orders` and their respective `classification`.

```
select 
orders.order_id,
orders.crit_1,
orders.crit_2,
orders.crit_3,
classifications.class_1

from 
orders

left join
classifications
on
orders.crit_1=classifications.crit_1 and
orders.crit_2=classifications.crit_2 and
orders.crit_3=classifications.crit_3

where
orders.others = "..."

group by 
orders.order_id,
orders.crit_1,
orders.crit_2,
orders.crit_3,
classifications.class_1
```

I need a GROUP BY at the end since the table classifications contains multiple entries with the combination of `crit_1`, `crit_2` and `crit_3`. But this isn't a problem since the needed `classification_1` is always the same for each combination of `crit_1, crit_2` and `crit_3`.

Now I want to create another query where I count just the number of each `classification_1` for the orders. Something like this:

```
class_1 | number
A       | 12
B       | 5
C       | 18
.       | .
```

But I don't know how without the whole selection of orders.order_id, `orders.crit_1`, `orders.crit_2`, `orders.crit_3` and `classifications.class_1`

I just want to count the `class_1` classifications for the query above.

Any suggestions?

---

*edit*

I tried it like suggested by Kaushik Nayak:

```
select 
--orders.order_id,
--orders.crit_1,
--orders.crit_2,
--orders.crit_3,
classifications.class_1,
count(*)

from 
orders

left join
classifications
on
orders.crit_1=classifications.crit_1 and
orders.crit_2=classifications.crit_2 and
orders.crit_3=classifications.crit_3

where
orders.others = "..."

group by 
--orders.order_id,
--orders.crit_1,
--orders.crit_2,
--orders.crit_3,
classifications.class_1
```

But the results are not correct and I have no idea how to reproduce those numbers.

A few examples:

```
| class_1 | query w/ | query w/o | query    |
|         | group by | group by  | count(*) |
---------------------------------------------
| A       | 654      | 2179      | 1024     |   
| B       | 371      | 1940      |  667     |   
| C       |  94      |  238      |  247     |
```

When I use my query with `group by` then I get 654 entries for `class_1` = A. 
When I make my query without `group by`then I get 2179 entries for `class_1`= A. 
And when I try the query with `Count(*)` then I get 1024 entries for `class_1` = A.

The last one is definitely not correct.

Comment: simple `SELECT c.class_1 ,
      COUNT(*) FROM orders o
    JOIN classifications c ON ... GROUP BY c.class_1`  . is it not working?

Comment: Sadly it did not work. I edited my question above to show you my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `GROUP BY` class_1 for your `classifications` table and add an `EXISTS` condition to check if there is an order.

```
SELECT
    c.class_1,
    COUNT(c.class_1) "number"
FROM
    classifications c
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            orders o
        WHERE
            o.crit_1 = c.crit_1
            AND   o.crit_2 = c.crit_2
            AND   o.crit_3 = c.crit_3
    )
GROUP BY
    c.class_1
ORDER BY
    1;
```